# Sinch didReceiveIncomingCall Never Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, sinch

I want to be able to make calls App-To-App using Sinch. I have followed the steps and converted the code into Swift. For some reason the method didReceiveIncomingCall is never called. I will paste some of my code so you can see how I initiated the SinchClient

in my `viewDidLoad` method I have.

```
sinchClient = Sinch.clientWithApplicationKey("key", applicationSecret: "secret", environmentHost: "sandbox.sinch.com", userId: "idOfUser")

sinchClient.setSupportCalling(true)
sinchClient.delegate = self
sinchClient.start()
sinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection()
```

Then I make a call from user1 to user2 using the following.

```
if(clientStarted){
  let callClient = sinchClient.callClient()
  callClient.callUserWithId("user2")
  sinchCall.delegate = self
}
```

This is my delegate methods for the `SINCallClientDelegate`

```
extension CallViewController: SINCallClientDelegate{
  func client(client: SINCallClient!, didReceiveIncomingCall call: SINCall!) {
    print("GOT ME AN INCOMING CALL")
    sinchCall = call
    sinchCall.delegate = self
    sinchCall.answer()
  }
}
```

For some reason, the method didRecieveIncomingCall never gets called. Sometimes I also get the following error:
*WARNING: Delegate for SINCallClient not assigned? Delegate should handle incoming call. (see -[SIN allClient Delegate notifyDelegate fIncomingCall:])*

I think maybe it might have something to do with `sinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection()` but I am not sure.

couple things to note is that I do know when my sinchClient is started because I listen for it in my delegate. When `clientDidStart` is called, I change the variable for `clientStarted: Bool`. I also have three delegates in one file (`SINCallClientDelegate`, `SINCallDelegate`, and `SINClientDelegate`). It waits for sinchClient to be started before making any calls.

Comment: is teh sinch client and callclient assigned variables that live thru the whole app lifecycle or at least the viewcontroller life cycle? Also you either need to startlisteneing to active connection or support push

Comment: Hey Christian, Good to hear from you so quickly. My issue was that although I set sinchClient.delegate = self, I never set sinchClient.callClient().delegate = self. After I set it, I got the function to work. I figured it out and tested it. Works incredible. By the way, I was just testing it so the sinchClient variable is temporarily for the viewcontroller lifecycle but I will have it for the app lifecycle to recieve calls from anywhere within the app. Thank you for looking into this for me.

Answer (score 2):

So my solution was so simple. I never set the `sinchClient.callClient().delegate = self`. Please read the comments on the question.

```
sinchClient.callClient().delegate = self
sinchClient.setSupportCalling(true)
sinchClient.delegate = self
sinchClient.start()
sinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection()
```

Comment: i hawe a job for you if you are awailbe can we talk this is my skype ahmedshakeelpk@gmail.com if you can come or please giwe me your skype id i want to directly talk to you